# Element colletion with nested embeddable doesn't work

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

Got java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.hibernate.property.access.spi.Setter.set(Object, Object)" because the return value of "org.hibernate.property.access.spi.PropertyAccess.getSetter()" is null, when trying to save an Entity using Hibernate.

I'm trying to save an entity object using hibernate and springboot.

This is the Product.class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "products")
public class Product implements Serializable {

  @ElementCollection
  @CollectionTable(
      name = "value_of_specs",
      joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "product_id")
  )
  private final Set<ValueOfSpec> valueOfSpecs = new HashSet<>();
  private final AuditInformation auditInformation;
  @Id
  @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
  @GeneratedValue(generator = "ID_GENERATOR")
  private Long id;
  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "created_by_id")
  private UserAccount createdBy;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "institution_id")
  private Institution institution;

  public Product() {
    auditInformation = new AuditInformation();
  }

  A lot of methods here ...
}
```

This is the ValueOfSpec.class

```
@Embeddable
public class ValueOfSpec implements Serializable {
  private final Specification specification;
  private final String value;

  public ValueOfSpec(Specification specification, String value) {
    this.specification = specification;
    this.value = value;
  }

  public ValueOfSpec() {
    this.value = null;
    this.specification = null;
  }

  public Specification getSpecification() {
    return specification;
  }

  public String getValue() {
    return value;
  }

  A bunch of methods here
  ...

}
```

This is the Specification.class

```
@Embeddable
public class Specification implements Serializable {
  private final String fieldName;
  private final String fieldType;
  private final boolean required;
  private final boolean readOnly;

  public Specification() {
    this.fieldName = null;
    this.fieldType = null;
    this.required = false;
    this.readOnly = false;
  }

  public Specification(String fieldName, String fieldType, boolean required, boolean readOnly) {
    this.fieldName = fieldName;
    this.fieldType = fieldType;
    this.readOnly = readOnly;
    this.required = required;
  }

  public String getFieldName() {
    return fieldName;
  }

  public String getFieldType() {
    return fieldType;
  }

  public boolean isReadOnly() {
    return readOnly;
  }

  public boolean isRequired() {
    return required;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (!(o instanceof Specification that)) return false;
    return isRequired() == that.isRequired() && isReadOnly() == that.isReadOnly()
        && Objects.equals(getFieldName(), that.getFieldName())
        && Objects.equals(getFieldType(), that.getFieldType());
  }

  @Override
  public int hashCode() {
    return Objects.hash(getFieldName(), getFieldType(), isRequired(), isReadOnly());
  }
}
```

This is the repository class and dao interface

```
@Repository
public class ProductRepositoryImpl implements ProductRepository {
  private final ProductDao dao;

  public ProductRepositoryImpl(ProductDao dao) {
    this.dao = dao;
  }

  @Override
  public void save(Product product) {
    dao.save(product);
  }

  @Override
  public Optional<Product> findById(Long id) {
    return dao.findById(id);
  }
}

public interface ProductDao extends JpaRepository<Product, Long> {
}
```

when I'm trying to save the product I got this error

```
2023-05-29T12:57:58.028-04:00 ERROR 22396 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed: org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: Could not instantiate entity:  : ca.eynoc.application.office.category.domain.Specification] with root cause

java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.hibernate.property.access.spi.Setter.set(Object, Object)" because the return value of "org.hibernate.property.access.spi.PropertyAccess.getSetter()" is null
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.mapping.internal.AbstractEmbeddableMapping.lambda$setValues$1(AbstractEmbeddableMapping.java:106) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.mapping.internal.EmbeddableMappingTypeImpl.forEachAttributeMapping(EmbeddableMappingTypeImpl.java:731) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
```

I don't know why I got this error.

Comment: Your entities/embeddables show get methods, but do you have set methods as well?

Comment: No needs for a set methods because Hibernate will use reflection and proxies to instantiate the embeddable class, in other entity it is working well, And the class causing the problem need to be immutable. So no need for a setter.

Comment: When I add a setter is not working.